# My Jar File won't open my .png files or my .wav files

Tags: java, jar

I know there are several similar questions out there, but the answers for the most part seem very specific. Anyway, my problem (as suggested by the title) is that my .jar file won't open .png files or .wav files (the only two file types I am using). However, Netbeans will run them just fine. I am importing the pngs as ImageIcons using

```
ImageIcon sun = new ImageIcon("Files\\Digital_Sun.png");
```

with "Files" being in my project folder. I have tried to load these files into my .jar, and when I open it with 7zip I can see that they are in there, however I seem to be unable to find the correct url for the files within the .jar. I have tried using the .getResourceAsStream() as some others have suggested, and that doesn't work for me either. Perhaps I am using it wrong, but the other answers and the documentation didn't help much there. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Edit: Here is my attempt at using InputStreams, which hasn't helped at all either. Can someone please show me the correct format for reading from a zip/jar file?

```
InputStream sunIS = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream("Files\\Digital_Sun.png"));
InputStream overIS = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream("Files\\overcast_digital.png"));
InputStream rainIS = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream("Files\\rain_digital.png"));
InputStream snowIS = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream("Files\\snow_digital.png"));
InputStream fairIS = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream("Files\\digital_fair.png"));
InputStream clearIS = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream("Files\\clear_digital.png"));
InputStream windyIS = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream("Files\\windy_digital.png"));
InputStream nullIS = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream("Files\\weather_unknown.png"));

ImageIcon sun;
ImageIcon overcast;
ImageIcon rain; 
ImageIcon snow;
ImageIcon fair;
ImageIcon clear;
ImageIcon windy;
ImageIcon nullWeather;

public DigitalClock() throws IOException, LineUnavailableException, URISyntaxException { //clock constructor
    super();
    sun = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(sunIS));
    overcast = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(overIS));
    rain = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(rainIS));
    snow = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(snowIS));
    fair = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(fairIS));
    clear = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(clearIS));
    windy = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(windyIS));
    nullWeather = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(nullIS));
```

Comment: Use the full path, use / instead of \\

Comment: I think you should go back to using getResourceAsStream and show us the code you used for that.

Comment: Most likely your current working directory is not where you think it is. Create a File object with your relative path you can use for ImageIcon, and use getAbsolutePath() to see what file it refers to.

Comment: @thorbjornRavnAndersen I just tried that, and it didn't help either. :/

Comment: Did you inspect the output from getAbsolutePath() to ensure that it was correct?

Comment: I did, and it works in Netbeans, but still won't work in the .jar

Comment: @cricekt_007 I added an edit for how I've been trying to get InputStream to work, as I read a couple other answers on other questions that said it would do the job, but I had no such luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, the following website gives a great explanation for using .getResourceAsStream()

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077352/java-se/smartly-load-your-properties.html